# not able to output specific row from xpath response

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

This is my first attempt at using xpath

I am attempting to pull out information of products on a list using the xpath interface via Scrapy on Python, specifically the prices from this url :

http://store.nike.com/gb/en_gb/pw/mens-shoes/7puZoi3?ipp=120#

As you can see the prices (going horizontally from left to right) is £90, £120, 
£100 ...

The following, will return a list of all the trainer prices on the page:

item['trainerPrice']= response.xpath('//span[@class="local nsg-font-family--base"]/text()').extract()
[image]

More so, the following will return the first "record":

item['trainerPrice']= response.xpath('string(//span[@class="local nsg-font-family--base"]/text())').extract()

[image]

However I am unsure, how to select the second record, i.e. u'\xa3120'

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the second item from the extracted list:

```
prices = response.xpath('//span[@class="local nsg-font-family--base"]/text()').extract() 
print(prices[1])
```

Though, I don't particularly like your locator. Instead I would take the `prices` div to rely on:

```
response.css('div.prices span.local::text')
```

Comment: thanks for that! i wasnt thinking properly, and was not indexing my array variable